# Monthly return of Stock Prices with time jump using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate monthly return of Stock from daily price of stocks using pandas dataframe.

DATA::

```
permno          date           prc

Firm A          1995-01-02       30

Firm A          1995-01-03       30.3

...

Firm B          1996-01-03       10.1
```

What I've tried so far::

```
df = DATA
#date columns are consisted with datestamps
df.loc[:, 'month'] = df.loc[:, 'date'].apply(lambda x : x.strftime('%Y%m'))
# **<code1>** choose first date from that month for each permno
df_ = df.sort_values('date').groupby(['permno', 'month']).first().reset_index()
# **<code2>**  caclulate monthly_return by getting pct_change()
df_['monthly_return'] = df_.sort_values('month').groupby('permno').prc.pct_change()
```

However, I just found out that some securities were not exchanged for some periods.

This leads to two problems:

1. Using  leads to select false-start-point for some securities. For example, If firm B's security was not traded in Jan 3 1997.(Assume that this is the first day the other securities were traded first time in Jan, 1997.)  selects the Jan, 4. 1997. Hence, leads to miscalculation of Monthly return for this security
2. Some securities were not traded for longer than a month.
   Suppose firm B was not traded for 1998.02. ~ 2001.12.. Then, using , we get
   "Monthly return rate for 2002.01" = "(price at 2002.01 - price at 1998.01)/(price at 1998.01)

Is there any simple way to deal with this kind of data with period-jump?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most convenient way is to drop the values that might generate misleading returns.

First create the an example data series with days as an index:

```
periods = 10000
my_index = pd.date_range('2016-07-01', periods=periods, freq='D')
data = np.random.randint(100,1000,periods)
ts = pd.Series(data=data, index=my_index, name='Daily Returns')
print(ts.head())
```

Example series looks like:
Question 1:

```
2016-07-01    348
2016-07-02    794
2016-07-03    650
2016-07-04    365
2016-07-05    291
Freq: D, Name: Monthly Returns, dtype: int64
```

Assigning a nan value in the start,

```
ts.iloc[0]=np.nan
```

Then resample the Series.
'BMS' stands for first business day.
'backfill()' to steer clear from forward looking bias.

```
ts=ts.resample('BMS').backfill().pct_change().dropna()
```

And in the resulting series, no observation for the first month and second month since no data to calculate returns.

```
2016-09-01    0.257343
2016-10-03   -0.296997
2016-11-01    0.433544
2016-12-01   -0.552980
2017-01-02   -0.390123
Freq: BMS, Name: Monthly Returns, dtype: float64
```

Question 2:
Insert more nan's and do the same:

```
ts.iloc[500:9000]=np.nan
ts=ts.resample('BMS').backfill().pct_change().dropna()
```

It will skip the nan months and their related returns.